# How to control image size when exporting to HTML via dvisvgm?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The org-mode source

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil creator:nil author:nil timestamp:nil num:t validate:nil
#+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

exports cleanly to HTML.

The `tex` option can be changed from `dvisvgm` to `dvipng` or `imagemagick` and it continues to work, but with a difference: When using `dvipng` or `imagemagick` the image size is constant; when using `dvisvgm` the image size is automatically adjusted to occupy the maximum space available. This means that the image size changes as the browser window is resized.

Is there a way to keep the image size constant when exporting images created by LaTeX snippets to HTML via SVG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ox-html uses `object` tags of the `org-svg` class to embed the generated SVG files. The default stylesheet has the following rule:

```
.org-svg { width: 90%; }
```

This leads to embedded SVGs that take up 90% of the screen space. Such as below:
[image: Equation takes 90% of the width]

This can be solved by overriding this in your own stylesheet:

```
.org-svg { width: auto; }
```

The output is then not scaled proportionally to the width anymore:
[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Any way to get the baseline to match up?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image), I think `.org-svg { width: auto; vertical-align:-7%; }` helps.