# Properly exporting latex to HTML from org-mode using dvisvgm / dvipng

Tags: org-mode, latex, html, mathjax

I need to export my org notes containing latex to HTML format. Example document :

```
#+latex_class: article
#+latex_header: \usepackage{chemfig} 
#+latex_header: \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
#+latex_compiler: pdflatex
#+options: tex:t
#+date: \today
#+title: something
#+author: me

 $$U_l=\frac{-A}{6}\Bigg[\frac{2}{\alpha^2-4}+\frac{2}{\alpha^2}+\ln{\Big(\frac{\alpha^2-4}{\alpha^2}\Big)}\Bigg]$$

 $$\ce{Zn^2+ <=>[+ 2OH-][+ 2H+] $\underset{\text{amphoteres Hydroxid}}{\ce{Zn(OH)2
 v}}$ <=>[+ 2OH-][+ 2H+] $\underset{\text{Hydroxozikat}}{\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^2-}}$}$$

 $$\chemfig{C*3(---)}$$
```

As I am using `chemfig` and other packages, using mathjax `#+options: tex:t` (default), won't render them in the HTML page:

[image: html page using mathjax]

Now I have two methods to solve this, either to use dvipng or dvisvgm.

### Using dvipng

To use dvipng, I changed mathjax to `#+options: tex:dvipng`, however as it can be seen, it does not render `chemfig` (and few other like `tikz`) properly (instead of 'C', there should have been a cyclopropane molecule) :

[image: html using dvipng]

`Imagemagick` also shows the same behaviour. So my **first question** is : how can I get `dvipng` to render the correct output?

### Using dvisvgm

Next I tried to use `dvisvgm` using `#+options: tex:dvisvgm`, and while it renders everything correctly, It also scales the images to almost the full width of the page :

[image: html using dvisvgm]

However I can fix this by modifying `.org-svg { width: 90%; }` to `.org-svg { width: auto; }` in the HTML source code as mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35716/29340). So my **second question** would be : How can I implement this setting for all org files whenever I export to HTML automatically? (as doing it manually each time I export would be tedious).

My **third question** would be that is it possible to use `mathjax` for normal math and `dvipng`/`dvisvgm` for other packages like packages like `chemfig` in the HTML output?

Please also suggest if there is another method to achieve this..

Answer (score 2):

Here is my (maybe somewhat hacky) fix. Put this in your config file.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-html
  (setq org-html-head
        (replace-regexp-in-string
         ".org-svg { width: 90%; }"
         ".org-svg { width: auto; }"
         org-html-style-default)))
```

---

How did I came up with this? Reading the [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#index-HTML_005fHEADLINE_005fCLASS_002c-property)'s section about CSS export, I found out about `org-html-style-default`. Then doing `C-h v org-html-style-default RET`, we read the documentation,

> The default style specification for exported HTML files.
> You can use ‘org-html-head’ and ‘org-html-head-extra’ to add to
> this style.  If you don’t want to include this default style,
> customize ‘org-html-head-include-default-style’.

We see that `org-html-style-default` is a string and we want to edit a small section of it. Namely, `.org-svg { width: 90%; }` to `.org-svg { width: auto; }`.

In order to do that, I thought we could just copy over `org-html-style-default` to `org-html-head` and replace the substring `.org-svg { width: 90%; }` to `.org-svg { width: auto; }`. Which is exactly what the above given code does.

Now, I am not an expert in elisp so I am not sure if the above way or the function `replace-regexp-in-string` is the best way of accomplishing what we want. I played around in the scratch buffer a bit to test that it does not change the original string which in our case is `org-html-style-default` and assigns a new one (`org-html-style`) after modifying the substring in the original string.